# Advice on reading in Excel file using C++

Tags: c++, excel, csv

I am writing a program which uses an exported Excel document from a POS system. I would like to read in the information from the excel document and then make my necessary calculations.

The problem I am having here is reading in the information from the excel file. I am open minded to converting it to CSV although it would be easier not to.

Here is a sample of the doc needed to be read:

```
//sale1

35204       Sales       180.19      Cash        5

3453        arnova  child pad       92709               1

//sale2

35205       Sales       614.78      Credit Card     7

3637        panasonic fz60      96409               1

2797        Bower SCB650        9309                1

2599        Dane-Elec 16GB SDHC     9709                1
```

I would need these datas read in for the first sale: eg: 1.35204, 2. 180.19, 3. Cash, 4.'5', 5.92709, 6.Cash

I should mention I am a second year programmer so please keep it basic! any help is appreciated thanks.

Comment: Why does "Cash" appear twice as item 3 and 6?  Why do you have the 5 in single quotes?  Why is there sometimes a space between the item number and its value and sometimes not?

Comment: So, reading a csv file isn't VERY complicated, but it's probably a bit more than you can expect someone to write as an answer here. Try writing some code to do it, and then ask SPECIFIC questions when you are stuck. If you have no idea, then perhaps you should consider some other career. [I'm not saying I expect you to solve it in the same amount of time that I would, after 32 years of programming, which is probably between 1-3 hours for a basic piece of code, and a few hours more if it has to be "perfect"].

Answer (score 2):

I see three options here.

1. Convert to CSV whatever way you can.
2. Use some 3rd party Excel reader like [Spreadsheet::ParseExcel](http://search.cpan.org/~jmcnamara/Spreadsheet-ParseExcel-0.59/lib/Spreadsheet/ParseExcel.pm) for
       Perl5 or [xlrd](http://www.python-excel.org/) for Python to convert to any format that your C++
       application can digest.
3. Use Excel through its COM or .NET (preferable, easier)
       [interfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/wss56bz7.aspx).